# Array data from table view to label

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsmutablearray, tableview

I've got a tableview setup to display data from an sqlite database, now what I am trying to do is setup a view to display further information from said database when the user clicks on a table cell.

From what I've read so far my understanding that this is done mainly in the prepareForSegue method inside the table view's controller?

Anyway, after a lot of googling I've ended up with this from an AppCoda tutorial [(link)](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/)...

```
 if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushToMountainInfo"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    UINavigationController *nav = segue.destinationViewController;
    MountainInformation *destViewController = [nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    MountainsObject *mountain = [self.mountains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    destViewController.nameLabel = mountain.name;
    NSLog(@"%@", mountain.name);
}
```

I put the NSLog there to test, and it does output the mountain's name to the log but the label remains blank when I run the app.

Can anybody please help?
Thanks..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay to shorten your code a bit..

```
 if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushToMountainInfo"]) {
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

MountainInformation *destViewController = [segue destinationViewController];// do this only if your segue is connected to the next one from previous, or else let it stay as you have, only change the later part
MountainsObject *mountain = [self.mountains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
destViewController.myMountain = mountain.name;
NSLog(@"%@", mountain.name);
}
```

Now create a property in MountainInformation.h file

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* myMountain;
```

Now your property is set to the name you want to set.
Now in viewDidLoad in MountainInformation.m

```
-(viewDidLoad){
self.labelToShowName.text = self.myMountain;
}
```

Hope this helps

[EDIT]
In MountainInformation.h Import your mountain class.

```
#import "MountainObject.h"
```

Change the property to

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) MountainObject *selectedMountain
```

Now in previous view controller.

```
 if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushToMountainInfo"]) {
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
UINavigationController *nav = segue.destinationViewController;

MountainObject *mountain = [self.mountain objectAtIndex.indexPath.row];
destViewController.selectedMountain = mountain;
}
```

In MountainInformation.h

```
-viewDidLoad{
NSString *mountainName = self.selectedMountain.name;
NSString *mountainRegion =self.selectedMountain.region;
NSString *mountainHeight =self.selectedMountain.height;
//and other properties. and then you can set it to a single label by using
self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Name - %@, Height- %@, Region- %@",mountainName, mountainHeight, mountainRegion];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to keep the uinavigationcontroller code in as my view is connected to one but it works now from your code.

Seriously thank you :)

Comment: no problem , please accept the answer so that if anyone encounters this same problem they can help themselves by the answer, cheers

Comment: Sorry to open this back up, and I swear I had this working just a minute ago... but how would I go about getting the data for different labels apart from the nameLabel?

I swear it was working a few minutes ago until I tried to add more again... unless I am going mad...

Comment: if you want to pass more than 1 name or data, i think you should consider a NSDictionary, i am updating the answer accordingly for your connivence

Comment: Can u explain me a bit as to what is it you want to do? i mean you want to pass one or multiple data?

Comment: Thanks, yes I want to pass multiple data so say when the user clicks on the mountain name they get taken to a view showing name, region, height etc.

I actually got it working by adding more strings in the MountainInformation.h file and then in the prepareForSegue method
    destViewController.myMountain = mountain.name;
    destViewController.mountainRegion = mountain.region;

Would NSDictionary be a better way of going about this?

Comment: Yes but that depends on do u want to show the multiple data (region, name etc) in one label? 
The best thing would be if you pass your mountain object in prepare for segue. Am editing the answer accordingly, you can use both if you want.

Comment: No all different labels, ok thanks I'll take a look :)

Comment: Well i have edited the answer and then saw that you wrote all different labels, But you get the point, create different label outlets and connect them and assign their text values accordingly. Hope this helped

Comment: Yes thank you I understand how you changed it, thanks again for all your help! You should get good karma now hah.